# Получение ссылки на пользователя через aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Я хочу что бы после нажатие клавиши пользователем мне в личные сообщение приходила ссылка на пользователя от бота.
И так как не у всех есть username то я бы хотел спросить возможно ли что бы мне приходила ссылка на пользователя с участием его юзер айди через aiogram и если так можно то как это сделать?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Я смотрел в интернете про инлайн упоминание но нечего не понял

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы при нажатии на инлайн кнопку,  бот отправлял вам данные о том кто нажал на эту кнопку?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В telegram есть "плюшка" позволяющая открыть переписку с  пользователем используя chat_id. Надеюсь решил ваш вопрос. @RitinaADM
p.s. Если память не подводит то работает только в мобильном приложении!

```
async def funcname(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    button_url = f'tg://openmessage?user_id={chat_id}'
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=button_text, url=button_url))
    await bot.send_message(admin_id, text=f'{chat_id}', reply_markup=markup)
```

Answer (score 0):

Кажется самый легкий вариант - message.from_user.url
Надеюсь помог